# BASH - alias calling another alias OR alias calling itself OR a recursive alias

Tags: bash, recursion, alias

Found another post here and it's possible that we can refer an alias in another alias.

**Ex: Both of the following aliases works!**

```
[gigauser@somenode01_new ~]$ alias cls="clear; ll"
[gigauser@somenode01_new ~]$ alias ccls='cd; cls'

[gigauser@somenode01_new ~]$ cls
total 12
-rw-r-----. 1 gigauser gigauser 879 Mar 30 22:24 aks1.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 gigauser gigauser 879 Mar 30 22:25 aks2.txt
-rwxr-x---. 1 gigauser gigauser 854 May  5 21:19 new-artifactory-license.json
drwxr-x---. 6 gigauser gigauser  64 Mar 30 21:21 tokens
[gigauser@somenode01_new ~]$ cd /tmp
[gigauser@somenode01_new tmp]$ pwd
/tmp

[gigauser@somenode01_new tmp]$ ccls
total 12
-rw-r-----. 1 gigauser gigauser 879 Mar 30 22:24 aks1.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 gigauser gigauser 879 Mar 30 22:25 aks2.txt
-rwxr-x---. 1 gigauser gigauser 854 May  5 21:19 new-artifactory-license.json
drwxr-x---. 6 gigauser gigauser  64 Mar 30 21:21 tokens
[gigauser@somenode01_new ~]$ pwd
/home/gigauser
```

**Similarly**, I created 2 aliases for myself.

First one, waits for me until I press **^C** (to break the loop) and the second one, just uses few docker commands and spits its intended output.

```
alias dkm='while true; do echo -e "\n-- `date`: Waiting for the $USER to come back."; sleep 900; done'

alias dstuff='sudo docker ps -a; echo; sudo docker image ls;echo; sudo docker volume ls; echo;'
```

The above aliases when run gives me:

**dkm**

```
-- Wed May 12 20:34:42 UTC 2021: Waiting for the gigauser to come back.
```

**dstuff**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                           NAMES
48c872e58b9b        artifactory-pro:latest   "/opt/giga/artifactor…"   2 days ago          Up 39 minutes       0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                                          artifactory
cccb871ba620        postgresql:latest        "/usr/local/pgsql/po…"   2 days ago          Up 39 minutes       5432/tcp                                                        artifactorydb

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgresql          latest              b1bdb78f4bcc        12 months ago       300MB
artifactory-pro     latest              3e51966e3d56        12 months ago       800MB

DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               artifactory-data
local               artifactorydb-data
```

BUT, why the following alias is NOT working, when I wanted to create another alias `dsc` using the **2 above aliases**:

```
alias dsc='dstuff; dkm'
```

Running **dsc** gives me:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Also, I was wondering, if an alias can refer itself i.e. Is this possible?

```
alias dsc='dstuff; dkm; dsc'
```

Basically, what Im trying to see if if an alias can call itself and show me `dstuff` output and then wait for some time (aka `dkm` dont kill me command) and then it calls itself again. Yes, I can `while :; do an_alias; done` too but curious if this (alias calling itself, i.e. **a recursive alias**) is possible.

Comment: If you're trying to do something at all complex, don't use an alias; they just have too many limits and confusing features to scale well. Use functions instead, or even entire scripts for bigger jobs. Anytime you run into trouble with an alias, try using a function instead (but remove the alias with `unalias` first, so there isn't a conflict).

Comment: `alias dkm='while true;` ugh, use a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dstuff` alias ends with `;`, so when `dsc` is expanded you get `echo;; dkm` at the end. Shell syntax doesn't allow two `;` in a row.

Get rid of the `;` at the end of the `dstuff` alias.